# Can calling system_clock::now() in the future give a time in the past?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Can calling system_clock::now() in the future give a time in the past? For example, because of daylight savings time?

What about calling system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()? Or is it guaranteed to always return later and later time points? Even without a guarantee, do all implementations do it a certain way in practice (if so, how)?

Comment: if a user changes with the system clock... there is not much you can do about it. Also `stead_clock` is guaranteed to be monotomic

Answer (score 2):

`std::chrono` offers both `system_clock` and `steady_clock` for general-purpose time tracking.

The `system_clock` class will rely entirely on the platform and thus if a user were to change the system time (or NTP etc.) it will obviously send you into the past/future. User changing **timezone** will not affect you providing you're not using local time.

`steady_clock` on the other hand is completely consistent (although VS2013 misimplemented this and it behaves just like `system_clock`, sadly)

Thus, if you need to know absolute time rather than simply the passing of time, I would suggest that you grab a value from `system_clock` at startup and use `steady_clock` from that point onwards.